# how to get data from solr for multiple value field of date

Tags: php, solr, lucene

I have multiple valued field "createddate" in solr collection which have following values

```
createddate : [
          "1:2014-08-08T18:36:47Z",
          "2:2014-08-08T18:37:07Z",
          "3:2014-08-08T18:37:31Z",
          "14:2015-07-29T16:56:29Z",
          "16:2015-09-21T12:25:43Z",
          "30:2015-11-30T08:00:00Z"
        ]
```

values in record is like key:date
now i want to fetch records whose created date less than current date and key specified by user like 1 or 2 or any

```
like created_date <= NOW()
```

i am not having any clue to how should i do it. i want solr query to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with your object in hand:

```
var result = [];
$.each(createddate, function(i, dateString){
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var currentDay = currentDate.getDay();
    var suppliedDate = new Date(dateString);
    var suppliedDay = suppliedDate.getDay();
    if(suppliedDay < currentDay){
        result.push(dateString);
    }
});
console.log(result);
```